# Type declaration in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

Please I learned Isabelle recently and I have problem in type declaration for "fun" or "definition" for example:

definition mos :: "real => real => real set"
where "mos u ≡  {(∀t∈T. ∃!x. vector(t,x)∈u)}"
please I couldn't understand how to define types for statements as I have many arguments.
I couldn't find clear description of how to declare types in the manuals, so if there is any helpful manual or reference that will be great.

Another thing, I tried to use command "typ" to check the varable type but it didn't work!.

Comment: Use the `term` command to check the type of a term.The rest of your question doesn't make sense.  Are you asking how to declare types?  The documents "Programming and Proving in Isabelle/HOL" and the Isabelle/HOL tutorial, both bundled with Isabelle, contain ample examples.  What are you struggling with?

Comment: Thanks Dominic, I found that putting "_" in the definition make Isabelle do automatic type inference. It works now, thanks again.